# Find the number of primes between $n$ and $n!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Question** Prove that between $n$ and $n!$ there are at least $n$ different primes.

I don't know how to approach to this problem

Answer (score 4):

This is false for n=1,2,3. For $n \geq 6 $ use the fact that $(n-1)! >2^n $ and then apply Bertrand's postulate , which guarantees the existence of a prime between $n$ and $2n$, n times.